# Activating a settings.xml Defined Maven Profile From POM File

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-profiles

Our enterprise team maintains a `settings.xml` file that defines various profiles that development projects can use with Maven to build their artifacts and install them in a repository. The expectation is that each project in Jenkins would define a -P parameter with the desired profile specified.

Here is my issue: The profile I need to use specifies a repository that is normally not visible to my project (a staged release repository), so anything in that repository cannot be depended upon without that profile being active. I need a way to activate that profile defined in `settings.xml` in my project's `pom.xml` file. Otherwise, when looking at my project in Eclipse, errors are shown in the `pom.xml` that dependencies cannot be resolved because the profile isn't active to make the repository visible.

Is there a way to activate a `settings.xml` defined profile in a `pom.xml` file? Alternatively, is there a way to tell Eclipse to always activate a profile for a particular project?

Comment: Why can't you activate the profile on the command line? I'm not sure I understood the problem.

Comment: Define build profiles in the settings.xml is never a good idea and in particular not in Jenkins. Jenkins has a good plugin: [Config File Provider](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin)  which handles this perfectly. furthermore it sounds like you should use a repository manager for your development...

Comment: @khmarbaise : I'll let the enterprise folks know about the plugin, thanks. And we are using a repository manager. My problem is the visibility of release candidates as dependencies to other projects in development.

Comment: @Tunaki : The problem is that Eclipse doesn't have a command line to specify during its normal workspace build. I did find a solution, it is in my self-provided answer.

Comment: @cneff You're wrong, it does ;). Create a custom Maven build (Run > Maven build...) and you have a textbox: "active profiles" that you can list. Then you can make that build configuration generic with the `${projectloc}` placeholder. Then you just need to select the project and run the configuration!

Comment: @Tunaki : I am not being clear. I am not talking about when I tell Eclipse to build the project using Maven. I am talking about when the Eclipse m2e plugin builds a project and reports any problems with the `pom.xml` file. This doesn't require a run configuration at all.

Comment: @cneff I see. That's a completely different problem yeah... Then I agree, I don't think there's a way to do it globally...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more research, I found a project specific Maven property in Eclipse where I can set the active profiles. You can set this by right-clicking on the project, select "Properties", and select "Maven". You are presented with a text entry box for "Active Maven Profiles (comma separated):".

That solved my problem.

I was looking for a more global solution in Eclipse rather than at the project level. But this seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `activateByDefault` tag to specify a default profile to use:

```
    <profile>
           <id>ProfileToActivate</id>
           <activation>
             <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
           </activation>
    </profile>
```

Comment: That works where the profile is defined, which in this case is the `settings.xml` file, which I don't have access to change. Additionally, that would make it active for everyone, when I'm the only project that wants it active all the time.